# Unable to activate the environment for my flask app on VSCode using the "source" command

Tags: visual-studio, flask, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code

While trying to create a flask environment on VSCode, it is showing an error saying that the "source" doesn't exist. Could you please tell me what is wrong here and how to create an environment on VSCode for my flask application? [image: This image shows the error of creating the desired environment]

Answer (score 1):

The command you executed is for linux. For windows use `flask_env\Scripts\activate`.

Comment: But the error seems to be with "source" and not the later part. The word "source" has to be replaced but I don't understand with what. Could you please tell me with what should I replace it with? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use the _source_ at all. It is a built-in linux command. When activating the virtual environment in a linux machine the code you tried is correct. From the screenshot I can see that you are using a windows device. To activate it in windows just run `flask_env\Scripts\activate`. See the documentation [here](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/legacy/userguide.html#activate-script).

Comment: Thank you so much!! :)